# icons show when i view website locally but when uploaded to live domain icons disappear, why?

Tags: html, svg, icons, jquery-svg

if i view my website locally i can see the icons ie. arrows and mobile navbar icons

but once i upload the site to a live domain the icons disapear

I'm not sure why this is, please assist. Here is my toggle menu not sure if it is relevant though

```
                        <ul>
                            <li class="special">
                            <a href="#menu" class="menuToggle"><span>Our Menu</span></a>
                            <div id="menu" style="background-color:#177ec1">
                                <ul>
```

here is the link to my site: http://gerlagroofing.co.za/default.asp

Comment: siteimages\logo.png backslashes are invalid, use / instead

Comment: Hi thanks i will remember that for future use